# How to wrap text with <a> tag in the .text() attribute? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags, element

I have `$userMsg.text('@' + msg.user + ': ' + msg.txt)`, and I want to make the user's name clickable, so that, for example, I could direct the page to the user's profile. However, when I throw `<a>` tags around `msg.user`, it doesn't seem to work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.text()` is for exactly that--text.  Instead, use `.html()`:

`$userMsg.html('<a href="' + user.profile + '">@' + msg.user + '</a>: ' + user.msg)`